# Optimizing summation loops

Tags: c++, optimization

I want to implement a hankel transformation in C++. The transformation itself (called `dht` and `idht`) from a vector `in` to `out` is defined  as

```
out(m) = \sum_{n=0}^N c_{m,n}*in(n)
```

with `c` defined as a matrix. Thus I implemented it in the following way (using `armadillo`):

```
void HT::dht(const arma::cx_colvec &in, arma::cx_colvec &out)
{
    if(out.size() != in.size())
        out = arma::cx_colvec(in.size());
//#pragma omp parallel for
    for(size_t i = 0; i < in.size(); ++i)
        F(i) = (in[i] * r_max / bessel_zeros[i]);

    std::complex<double> G_0;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < in.size(); ++i)
    {
        G_0 = 0;
        for(size_t j = 0; j < in.size(); ++j)
            G_0 += c(i, j) * F[j];
        G(i) = G_0;
    };

//#pragma omp parallel for
    for(size_t i = 0; i < in.size(); ++i)
        out(i) = (G[i] / rho_max * 
        bessel_zeros[i]);

}
```

What is the best way to improve the speed of this function (which is the most time-consuming function in my code, according to valgrind)? I already tested the function with OpenMP, using the `#pragma`-commands, but that even slowed it down. What else could I do to improve the speed of the function?

Currently the program is compiled using

```
g++ -I -O2 -g -march=native -std=gnu++17 -fopenmp main.cpp -lm -larmadillo -lgomp -lpthread -lX11 -L/opt/boost/lib -lboost_system -o main
```

Edit: I noticed that I can write the code also more concisely as

```
F = in % (r_max / bessel_zeros);
G = c * F;
out = G % (bessel_zeros / rho_max);
```

which gives me a speedup of 12.557 ms vs 10.082 ms for 500 elements, and 359.787 ms vs 312.383 ms for 2500 elements. Is there still something I can optimize?

Comment: What is the size of vectors?

Comment: Fixed, but depending on the run between 500 elements and 50000 elements.

Comment: did you see the difference between 500 and 50000 elements in processing per element?

Comment: Until now I do not want to time 50000 elements (too time consuming), but I am testing shorter vector sizes now

Comment: This feels like a better fit on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: According to [the docs](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Mat), Armadillo matrices are stored in column-major ordering.  Thus you will likely be causing a gazillion cache misses for larger sizes.  Try switching the order of your nested loops.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Inb4 the optimizer switched it for you already :)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: Now I am using armadillo-operations, so I think that problem does not exist anymore

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate 'r_max / bessel_zeros' and 'r_max * bessel_zeros' once and store them in an array.

Is there a reason why you only Compiler with optimization level 2 (-O2) and not 3?

Rest looks good. I dont think you can seed it up alot.

Comment: -O3 even slows it down, according to my measurements

Comment: Do you habe any idea why this happens?

Comment: Assume some bad optimizations, but else no idea